# How to assign a dataframe as NULL?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `mydata[[i]]` that consists of dataframes inside it

example:

```
  str(mydata[[1]])
  NULL
  dim(mydata[[1]])
  NULL
  str(mydata[[2]])
 'data.frame':   154 obs. of  1 variables:
  $ mod                  : num  0.0993 0.1003 0.0855 0.077 0.0954 ...
  > dim(mydata[[2]])
  [1] 154   1
  # until mydata[[125]]
```

As you can see there is nothing in some so it returns `NULL` as for (mydata[[1]]) but exist some info for others as for `mydata[[2]]`

what I need is to say `if sd(mydata[[i]]$mod)> 5 return mydata[[i]] as NULL`

Comment: Fixed it, it was due to NULL elements in the data.  Please check the solution posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list` with `lapply` and use the `if/else` condition.

```
 ind <- sapply(mydata, is.null)
 ind1 <- sapply(mydata[!ind], function(x) all(is.na(x$obs)))
 mydata[!ind][!ind1] <- lapply(mydata[!ind][!ind1], 
       function(x) if((sd(x$mod)/sd(x$obs, na.rm=TRUE))>5) NULL else x)
```

#### data

```
  mydata <- list(NULL, data.frame(obs=c(NA, 1:3,5), mod=c(24, 25, 39, 85, 20)),
           NULL, data.frame(obs=1:5, mod=c(24:28)), data.frame(obs=NA, mod=c(2,24)))
```

Comment: @temor Are you dividing `sd(x$mod)` by the logical element

Comment: @temor Try `sd(x$mod, na.rm=TRUE)/sd(x$obs, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @temor It is based on your description that there are NA elements in obs

Comment: @temor Using the example `mydata[[2]]$v1[2] <- NA;lapply(mydata, function(x) if(!is.null(x) & (sd(x$mod)/sd(x$v1, na.rm=TRUE))>5) NULL else x)`

Comment: @temor In that case, may be you can also add another condition `if(!is.null(x) & all(is.na(x$obs)) & sd(x$mod)/sd(x$obs)>5), `

Comment: @temor I am creating an example to test for cases that have all NAs

Comment: @temor Just updated with a new example, check if that helps